# How to combine a number frequency data set into tradional lottery number calculation?

Tags: statistics, combinations, lotteries

I'm trying to figure out how to combine historical lottery data with a traditional lottery number probability calculation technique to result in a more "accurate" probability of a number being drawn, but I don't know how to bring everything together in an accurate way.

The lottery pulls 6 numbers from a range of 1 - 75.  In order for users to win, they need to match 1 to 6 numbers.

I'm using the following formula to calculate the probability of a winning number being drawn where n = total number of available numbers, k = total number of numbers in the winning combination for the jackpot, and x = total number of user numbers that match the winning set.
$$
\ =\frac{C(k,x)*C(n-k,k-x)}{C(n,k)}\
$$

For example, to calculate the probability of 1 winning number, I'm using the following (simplified) formula:
$$
C(6,1) * C(69,5)/C(75,6)
= 0.3348789
$$

I also have a frequency table of every number telling me how much it's been pulled in a winning set of numbers. For example:

```
# | Number of times drawn
---------
1 | 652
2 | 601
3 | 634
....
73| 587
74| 599
75| 661
```

How can I utilize the frequency of each number being drawn in a winning set of lotto numbers into the probability calculation?

Edit:  Upon investigation, it looks like an ANOVA test might work, but I don't know how to construct it properly.  Is that the correct route?

Comment: Do you mean that you do not believe / don't want to assume that all numbers are equiprobable, and then compute each number probability based on frequencies? How many draws do you have in you history?

Comment: The empirical probability to draw a 1 is  $\hat p_1=\frac{652}{\underbrace{652+601+634+\ldots+587+599+661}_{\text{75 summands}}}$ Similar calculation for $\hat p_i$, where $2 \leq i \leq 75$

Comment: @A.G. Correct, even if the numbers are overall equiprobable, I would like to take their individual frequencies as a computational factor when considering them.  I have 3564 draws in the history.

Comment: @callculus are you suggesting I use empirical probability to compute the probability of each available number in the lottery?  How would the result of that calculation then factor into the more general lottery calculation?

Comment: >>Are you suggesting I use empirical probability to compute the probability of each available number in the lottery?<< Yes. >>How would the result of that calculation then factor into...<< You calculate the 6 $\hat p_i$ your are interested in. Then you can calculate the probability to draw these six numbers.

Comment: One good thing to do is to check whether the distribution of draws is consistent with the numbers being equiprobable.  You can do a chi-squared test to see.  You are assuming the observed frequency is the actual probability for each number rather than a fluctuation away from the norm.  Do you have any evidence for this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you want is to compute empirical frequencies as proxies for probabilities, the formula is straightforward. 
$$
P(\text{number $i$ is selected at a draw})\approx
f_i={\text{number of draws with $i$ selected}\over {\text{total number of draws}}}.
$$
With your data
$$
f_1={652\over 652+...+661}
$$
etc. These frequencies should verify
$$
\sum_i f_i = 6
$$
as 6 numbers are drawn.